# RDP Access for AD Service Account?

Tags: active-directory, windows-services

We're trying to lock down our service accounts as much as possible.

Does an Active Directory Service Account need Remote Desktop access?

What's the minimum permissions an AD Service Account would require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum permissions an AD service account needs are the minimum permissions to do the task that you've created the service account to perform.

If you created the service account so it can RDP into another machine and do something, then yes, it needs RDP access.

If you are not using it to RDP to another machine, then no, it doesn't need RDP access.

It's up to you to decide.